# Androgenization refers to masculinity, but Androgynous refers to masculinity and femininity. Why?

Tags: meaning

I recently came across the word "androgenization" which I have found to mean "possess male hormones". I found this rather strange, because to be androgynous is to have neither/both male and female characteristics. These words are so similar, yet their definitions are far apart. Why? Is there a word that means "possess female hormones"?

Thanks!

Comment: Because *gen* is “make” but *gyn* is “girl”. This is General Reference.

Comment: As waywardeev says, Malapropism of greek words.

Answer (score 1):

Androgynous comes from greek. **andros** is the genitive of the Greek word for man and **gyne** is woman. Put together you get 'Androgynous', having qualities of both man and woman.

I've never heard 'androgenization' before, in fact Microsoft Word doesn't even recognize it, so I suppose it's a neologism. It's etymology seems pretty straightforward: **andros** again comes from the Greek for 'man,' 'genization' comes from **genesis**, Greek for origin.

They seem very similar because they share **andros** and 'gen' and 'gyn' sound alike.

Comment: The _gen-_ root comes from the same source as _genetic_: the Proto-Indo-European root [_*ɡen-_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf) 'give birth to; be born; offspring'. The _gyn-_ root, on the other hand, comes from the PIE root [_*ɡʷen-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080627204018/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE182.html) 'woman'. _Andros_ comes from the PIE root [_*ner-_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628030728/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE345.html) '(masculine) man'.